# How to display image?

Tags: codeigniter

I store the name of the image in database.now i retrive the name of the image.i try to display the image like this.this is my view.images is my uploaded folder name.

```
<?php include('inc/header.php');?>

<div class="main">
    <?php
        foreach ($image as $row) {
            echo "<img src='<?php echo base_url();?>images/$row->image'>";
        }

    ?>


</div>
<?php include('inc/footer.php');?>
```

but the image is broken.how can i fix them.please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work: `echo "<img src='".base_url()."images/".$row->image."'>`

You don't need to reopen php tag inside echo statement.

> Are you sure that image name is correct, and do you have image
>   extension in name?
>
> Also try to put `images/$row->image` inside php tag:
>
> ```
> echo "<img src='<?php echo base_url().'images/'.$row->image.'png';?>'>";
> ```

Comment: my database field image store the image name with its extension..when i inspect the element instead of the path there is php code in image src..like <img src="<?php echo base_url();?images/bird.jpg">

Comment: Try this: `echo "<img src='".base_url()."images/".$row->image."'>`

Comment: You don't need to reopen php tag in echo statement